# Making countinuous table

Tags: tables, dictionaries

I want to make a table for something like index, but instead of page numbers  importing the meaning of the world in my language (something like a dictionary). I want to have two tabulars in each page. As I know there is three methods for making such table:

1. Change the page style to two column page.
2. Using two minipage.
3. Draw a side by side tabular

but none of these, break the table at the suitable position to draw it's continuation it in the side table. Is there any solution?

Comment: How about `longtable`?

Comment: @marmot: I didn't know this enviroment. Is it suitable?

Comment: Well, it allows you to have a continuous table that runs over several pages. But from your description it might also be that you are looking for the `paracol` package.